# Why did Birkhoff & Mac Lane prove the uniqueness of a ring's additive identity this way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In a commutative ring, it is easy to show that there can only be one additive identity. For if $0_{1}$ and $0_{2}$ are additive identities, it follows that $0_{1}=0_{1}+0{_2}=0_{2}+0_{1}=0_{2}$.

But in the *Survey of Modern Algebra* by Birkhoff & Mac Lane, they claim that the uniqueness of the additive identity in a ring follows from the following proposition:

> If $z$ in $ \mathfrak{R}$ has the property that $z+a=a$ for all $a$ in $ \mathfrak{R}$, then $z = 0$.

For completeness I'll include the proof:

> By universal instantiation, let $a=0$. Then $z+0=0$ certainly implies $z=0$,
>   hence $z$ must be $0$ for all $a$ which satisfy the above property.

Here's the question: Why did they resort to such a proposition to prove the uniqueness property, when there's an easier and shorter proof? Is it more generalisable to other algebraic structures? If so, please explain.

Comment: This looks to me like a typo--if they say $a=0$ instead, then this is just the usual proof.  With $a=1$, it's not at all clear why they say "certainly".

Comment: Ooops --- typo's my fault! Corrected. Why are they the same?

Comment: I don't see any significant difference between what you and they say.